# Calculate new column value based on values from other df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two data-frames.
First contains some info based on index like below:(First column is the index)

```
index,Dist,Individual
Big,100,50
Small,50,100
```

second dataframe:

```
id,hour,machinesize,type 
1,10,Big,Dist
2,20,Small,Individual
```

I want to calculate the values like below:

hour* (values from df1 based on **Big,Dist**)
ie  10 *100
My final output will look like below:

```
id,hour,calc
1,10,1000
2,20,2000
```

The 'machinesize' value = 'index' in first df

Comment: If your values based on df1 does not change, then you can just use: df2['calc'] = df2.hour * df1[df1.index=='Big'].Dist ?

Comment: No it is coming as 'nan'

Comment: why is `calc` for `id==1` of your output is `100`? Should it be `1000`?

Comment: Then should `id==2` gives `1000` as well, since it's a small machine size?

Comment: No..hour=20*100=2000

Comment: Then u need to `Dist*Machinesize` and it doesn't depends on type of `Machinesize`. Opposite of this is what you have mentioned in your question

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the desired result:

```
result = df2.merge(df1, left_on='machinezise', right_on='index')

result.assign(calc=result.lookup(result.index, result.type)*result.hour)[['id', 'hour', 'calc']]

result

   id  hour  calc
0   1    10  1000
1   2    20  2000
```

Comment: The 2nd row value should be 2000 (20*100)